# Machine learning: training model from test data

Tags: machine-learning

I was wondering if a model trains itself from the test data as well while evaluating it multiple times, leading to a over-fitting scenario. Normally we split the training data into `train-test` splits and I noticed some people split it into 3 sets of data - `train`, `test` and `eval`. `eval` is for final evaluation of the model. I might be wrong but my point is that if the above mentioned scenario is not true, then there is no need for an `eval` data set.

Need some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to evaluate how well a model will perform in the 'wild' is to evaluate its performance on a data set it has not seen (i.e., been trained on) -- assuming you have the labels in a supervised learning problem.

People split their data into train/test/eval and use the training data to estimate/learn the model parameters and the test set to tune the model (e.g., by trying different hyperparameter combinations). A model is usually selected based on the hyperparameter combination that optimizes a test metric (regression - MSE, R^2, etc.; classification - AUC, accuracy, etc.). Then the selected model is usually retrained on the combined train + test data set. After retraining, the model is evaluated based on its performance on the eval data set (assuming you have some ground truth labels to evaluate your predictions). The eval metric is what you report as the generalization metric -- that is, how well your model performs on novel data.

Does this help?

Comment: Well it doesn't really answer my question directly but I got what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have train and test datasets. Train dataset is the one in which you know the output and you train your model on train dataset and you try to predict the output of Test dataset.

Most people split train dataset into train and validation. So first you run your model on train data and evaluate it on validation set. Then again you run the model on test dataset.

Now you are wondering how this will help and of any use?
This helps you to understand your model performance on seen data(validation data) and unseen data(your test data).

Here comes bias-variance trade-off into picture.
https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-to-the-bias-variance-trade-off-in-machine-learning/

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a binary classification example where a student's previous semester grades, Sports achievements, Extracurriculars etc are used to predict whether or not he will pass the final semester.

Let's say we have around 10000 samples (data of 10000 students).

Now we split them:

Training set - 6000 samples

Validation set - 2000 samples

Test set - 1000 samples

The training data is generally split into three (training set, validation set, and test set) for the following reasons:

1) **Feature Selection:** Let's assume you have trained the model using some algorithm. You calculate the training accuracy and validation accuracy. You plot the learning curves and find if the model is overfitting or underfitting and make changes (add or remove features, add more samples etc). Repeat until you have the best validation accuracy. Now test the model with the test set to get your final score.

2) **Parameter Selection:** When you use algorithms like KNN, And you need to find the best K value which fits the model properly. You can plot the accuracy of different K value and choose the best validation accuracy and use it for your test set. (same applies when you find n_estimators for Random forests etc)

3) **Model Selection:** Also you can train the model with different algorithms and choose the model which better fits the data by testing out the accuracy using validation set.

So basically the Validation set helps you evaluate your model's performance how you must fine-tune it for best accuracy.

Hope you find this helpful.